# How to solve sprite button flicker in unity ar

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I created Ar visiting card, in that I added buttons. Whenever target images comes the buttons keeps flickering. How to solve this issue? Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Z-Fighting. One solution might be to move the buttons a tiny amount away from the tracking image. Otherwise some meshes could overlap.